# My fastapi app getting crushed on production server but also working on localhost

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

After every one or two hours my fastapi app getting crushed. I can see those log from my server.

```
[UID:1438][3585218] Child process with pid: 3585712 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
[UID:1438][3647755] Child process with pid: 3647765 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
[UID:1438][3647755] Child process with pid: 3647775 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
```

I have others python app running on my server without any issue. After every one or two hour my fastapi app getting crushed. here is my **database.py** code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
 

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "mysql+pymysql://<>:@<>/<>"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

**main.py**

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    openapi_url: str = "/openapi.json"


settings = Settings()

app = FastAPI(openapi_url=settings.openapi_url)

origins = [
     
    "http://localhost:3000",
     
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
     
     
    
)


#create tables
models.Base.metadata.create_all(engine) 
app.include_router(user.router)
app.include_router(authentication.router)
app.include_router(blog.router)
app.include_router(admin.router)

@app.get("/",tags=["Home page"])
def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Comment: "getting crushed" means being disconnected or some other error ?

Comment: D.L  yes my app getting disconnected after every one or two hour. If I manually go to my server and restart the app then it's working

Comment: you can add a check in the code, say every 15 mins, that the server is working and reconnect...

Comment: The issue can also be caused by MySQL (if you have low RAM on the server)... Check your MySQL optimization/configuration

Comment: @itsmehemant7 how to check mysql configrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After move to aws ec2 from my shared hosing my fast api app working fine. So You can't run your fastapi app on low configuration shared hosting. You need minimum 1 GB of ram and 2 cpu core on your vps hosting for run your fast api app smoothly.